How to display default TV volume in Tizen web app?
I'm developing a web application for Tizen Smart TVs, and I need to display the current volume level of the TV on the screen when the app starts.
I need to display the OnScreenDisplay of Volume when changing the volume. I know you can use tizen.tvaudiocontrol.setVolumeUp() or tizen.tvaudiocontrol.setVolume(10) to change volume, but I don’t know how to display the OSD volume of a Samsung tv.
I've been searching through the Tizen documentation but couldn't find a clear way to display the current volume level in TV (The default OSD).
Can anyone guide me on how to display the default OSD TV volume in a Tizen web app? Any code examples or pointers to the right APIs would be greatly appreciated!

Have you seen the entry in the docs for getVolume()? There's even an example of how to use it under setVolumeDown()

yes i have seen it @RoryMcCrossan, but it just get the volume of the device.... not displaying the default OnScreenDisplay of volume....

Have you tried fetching the current value then using setVolume() to that value to see if the OSD appears? Failing that, if the value needs to change for the OSD to appear, get the value and quickly set it to one lower, then back to what it was again.

i have tried it, but it's still doesn't display the OSD....

It is the specification of this API that the OSD of the TV does not appear when you call the API you mentioned. since a webapp may display its own volume UI, this API does not display the OSD in consideration of it.

does tizen provide an API to call the OSD of volume?
